# How to plot VWAP in pine script for specific timeframe period?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

I'm using the built-in VWAP function in Tradingview and I'd like to plot only the VWAP line from the start of the selected timeframe period to the current bar. Nothing should be plotted before the selected timeframe period.

In the example below I'm plotting the VWAP with a monthly anchor, so it resets every month. And I'd like to plot from the start of the current month only and nothing before that. When a new month starts it should reset and anchor to the new month.

The plot()function have the show_last argument which I first thought could be a way to write some conditions, but I failed. It seems like the show_last argument isn't very flexible and only allows input integers.

Any ideas and suggestions how to achieve what I*m looking for would be much appreciated!

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
vwap = ta.vwap(close, timeframe.change("1M"))
plot(vwap, show_last=30)
```

[Illustration of the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oORPL.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *good* way to do this, unfortunately. Plotting only the last month would require your script to know when the last month begins at the very start of the calculation, which is info that it cannot access yet. Additionally, when a script has plotted something and the bar closed, the script can no longer change or remove these values.

But... there is a possible way I can think of. You can use `timenow` to check the time when the script was last updated, and then subtract 1M from that time and add this to the condition that you use to restart the VWAP anchor. The script below seems to work on my end:

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)
tf = "1M"
// I added an extra day there (1440 * 60 * 1000) to make sure we go far enough into the past
// 1M is 30.4 days so otherwise there could have been issues with 31 day months
isLastMonth = time >= timenow - timeframe.in_seconds(tf) * 1000 + 1440 * 60 * 1000
vwap = ta.vwap(close, timeframe.change(tf) and isLastMonth)
plot(vwap)
```

Note that, if this script will be left on the chart without refreshing it and the month changes, the older data will still be on the chart. Refreshing the chart should clear it.

Comment: Right. I see. My suspicion was that a work around was needed. And the solution you presented works great.

BTW I stumbled upon this closed source indicator that seems to be doing what I wanted to achieve: https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000652199-vwap-auto-anchored/

Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: This indicator is closed source because it's a built-in not written in Pine, and it's not written in Pine specifically because the functionality you seek cannot be implemented in Pine at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this instead to be able to 'roll' the timeframe period and avoid the period reset from timeframe.change:

```
q = timenow - 30.4*3*86400000

f(x, y, z)=>
    ini = time>=x and time[1]<x
    src = hlc3 * volume
    vol = volume
    dev = hlc3*hlc3*volume
    src := ini?src:src+src[1]
    vol := ini?vol:vol+vol[1]
    dev := ini?dev:dev+dev[1]
    vwap = src/vol
    dev1 = math.sqrt(dev/vol-vwap*vwap)*y
    dev2 = math.sqrt(dev/vol-vwap*vwap)*z 
    [vwap, dev1, dev2]

[vwap, dev1, dev2] = f(q, 1.0, 2.0)
plot(vwap)
plot(vwap+dev1)
plot(vwap-dev1)
plot(vwap+dev2)
plot(vwap-dev2)
```